# How to make Justified Gallery jQuery plugin work with lighGallery jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, lightgallery

I'm building my image gallery with justified Gallery jQuery plugin (http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery) and trying to use lightGallery plugin (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery) work as a lightbox.

Here's the code that I use to trigger both:

HTML:

```
<div id="mygallery">
  <a href="imagepath/img.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="imagepath/img-thumb.jpg" alt="img description"></a>
  <a href="imagepath/img.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="imagepath/img-thumb.jpg" alt="img description"></a></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
    rowHeight: 120,
    margins: 5,
  }).on('jg.complete', function () {
$('#mygallery a').lightGallery({
  thumbnail: true,
  animateThumb: false,
  showThumbByDefault: false
});
```